# Zip Folder created using php is not downloading and extracting properly

Tags: php, mysql

```
class ZipCreate{

function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path)
{
$zip = new ZipArchive();

//create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful

if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {

   exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");

}

//add each files of $file_name array to archive

foreach($file_names as $files)  {

$zip->addFile($file_path.$files,$files);

}

$zip->close();

chmod($archive_file_name, 0777);

// http headers for zip downloads

header("Pragma: public");

header("Expires: 0");

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

header("Cache-Control: public");

header("Content-Description: File Transfer");

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($archive_file_name)."\"");

header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

header("Content-Length: ".filesize($archive_file_name));

ob_end_flush();

@readfile($archive_file_name);      

}

}
```

The above code is working fine in local and it is downloading the zip file properly in local unix system. The folder in which the zip should be created is having 777 permissions. But in local windows system and online server it is giving network error.. can anyone tell what could be the problem in the above code.

Comment: The above code working properly in linux systems but not working in windows. what are the headers for downloading zip folder in windows??

Comment: Can i get any reply for my above question.. I have seen all posts related to this and tried it on production server.. event though it is giving failed-Network error when we download the zip in online production server... anyone can help me please..